# SSIS connectivity to attunity

Tags: sql-server, oracle, visual-studio-2012, ssis, attunity

I am getting this error in SSIS

```
****Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0202040
Error at <Task name> [OLE DB Destination [81]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Multiple-step 
OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".****Error at Populate datacombined data [OLE DB Destination [81]]: Failed to open a fastload rowset for <Table name>. 
Check that the object exists in the database.
```

Please can anyone tell me if the installed versions of software are correct for the below mentioned version of visual studio and Sql server which is installed on my machine:

I am using 64bit- windows 8.1 enterprise.

Sql server : Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64) Jun 28 2012 08:36:30 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Microsoft visual studio : Microsoft visual studio 2012 shell version 11.0.50727.1

32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studiobase.
ODTwtihODAC : ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit
64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) 
ODAC121010_x64

Attunity :  I installed attunity version 1.2 -- 32 and 64 bit.

I am able to connect to the oracle DB and able to fetch the data, but the problem is in data access mode of the destination oracle server. It's throwing the error when I set the data access mode as table or view - fast load.

Can anyone please help to resolve this issue. Is there any setting which I need to change in visual studio after installing attunity?

Please note that this is an already existing package and I am trying to open and run it. This package does not throw any error in another machine with data access mode as fast load.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you really need to use the correct version of the driver.
In order to force VS to use 32 or 64 libs go to Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging and change Run64BitRuntime.
[image: change debug mode]

Comment: I tried , but not working . Can you please let me know if any settings needs to be changed after installing attunity

Comment: hm.. not sure that anything should be changed over there. what drivers have you installed 32 or 64?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is the correct version of the Attunity Connector. For connecting to MSSQL 2008, we are using 2.0, 3.0 and 4.0 all installed together. I would read the version descriptions that you can get to from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/attunity-connectors?view=sql-server-2017